# Is it allowed for a string to begin with a number in Java

Tags: java, string

Is it allowed to name a string e.g. 0_Ahnung?

Comment: Do you mean the string's content or its name?

Comment: You can have the *content* of the string be anything you want: `String myString = "0_Ahnung";` is OK. However that's *not* allowed for the *name* of the string: `String 0_Ahnung = "myString";` isn't OK. It's not clear which you're asking about. You could of course have found this out by **simply trying it**.

Comment: beside trying as @jonrsharpe suggested you could also read the free tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: "0_Ahnung" is German and means "0_knowledge". Something is wrong with this question...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a string can begin with a digit. A variable cannot.

```
String myString = "0_abc";
```

is a valid string.

```
String 0_abc = "aaa";
```

is not a valid defenition.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is found in section 3.8 of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) - which clearly states that the first character of a Java identifier name (such as a variable name) cannot be a digit.